# the spectrum of a bounded linear operator on $X\times X$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

If we consider $X\neq\{0\}$ to be a complex Banach space then the product $X\times X$ is a Banach space with the norm $\|(x,y)\|=\|x\|+\|y\|$. $T(x,y)=(x + y,x - y)$ is then a bounded linear operator on $X\times X$. Find $\sigma(T)$ and the subsets $\sigma_p(T),\sigma_c(T), \sigma_r(T)$, where $\sigma(T)$ is the spectrum of operator $T$, and the subsets are the point spectrum, the continuous spectrum, and the residual spectrum, respectively.

I am stuck at this problem. I know that the spectrum is supposed to be the set of eigenvalues, which I am supposed to find with matrices I believe. So I'd have to compute $T-\lambda I$ but I am not sure how the matrix of $T$ looks in this space? Then of course I'd have to compute the subsets which seems even harder.

Comment: Have you studied Banach space theory/operator theory? The question has nothing to do with matrices.

Comment: Yes I have, but I thought that the spectrum is calculated through the matrix of $T$ with respect to some basis? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Your line of thinking completely fails in the case of infinite dimensional spaces. I am sorry to say this, but if I post an answer to this question you may not be able to understand it.

Comment: Ah, I see. Of course I have the literature but I made a mistake. Maybe I will be able to follow the answer, so any help is appreciated. @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Just follow the definitions: you can see that $(T-\lambda I)(x,y)=(u,v)$ has a unique solution for any $(u,v)$ iff $\lambda \neq 1\pm i$. In this case $(u,v) \to (x,y)$ is easily seen to be a  bounded operator. Hence spectrum of $T$ is $\{1+i,1-i\}$. There are no eigen values as seen by solving $T(x,y)=\lambda (x,y)$.  Now use definition of continuous and residual spectrum.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why are you saying that there are no eigenvalues? $\lambda=\pm \sqrt{2}$ and $y=(\pm\sqrt{2}-1)x$ are the solution of $T(x, y)=\lambda(x, y)$, aren't they?

Comment: @AndreyGorbunov You are right made a mistake.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy how did you get $\lambda=1\pm i$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$
This isn't the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. to any basis but it can still be useful because formally$$T\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}, \quad \forall\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix} \in X \times X $$

Its characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^2-2$ so the eigenvalues are $\pm \sqrt{2}$.

Check that for $\lambda\ne \pm\sqrt{2}$ we have
$$(T-\lambda I)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}1-\lambda & 1 \\ 1 & -1-\lambda \end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix} = -\frac1{\lambda^2-2}\begin{bmatrix}\lambda+1 & 1 \\ 1 & \lambda-1 \end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix} $$ 
and this is a bounded linear map so $\lambda \notin \sigma(T)$.

On the other hand, for $\lambda = \pm\sqrt{2}$, we have
$$T\begin{bmatrix}(1\pm\sqrt{2})y \\ y\end{bmatrix} = \pm\sqrt{2}\begin{bmatrix}(1\pm\sqrt{2})y \\ y\end{bmatrix}$$
for any $y \in X, y \ne 0$ so $\pm \sqrt{2} \in \sigma_p(T)$.

Therefore $\sigma(T) = \sigma_p(T) = \{\pm\sqrt{2}\}$ and $\sigma_r(T) = \sigma_c(T) = \emptyset$.

---

We have
\begin{align}
\left\|(T-\lambda I)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \end{bmatrix}\right\| &= \frac1{|\lambda^2-2|}\left\|\begin{bmatrix}(\lambda+1)x+y \\ x+(\lambda-1)y \end{bmatrix}\right\| \\
&= \frac1{|\lambda^2-2|}(\|(\lambda+1)x+y \| + \|x+(\lambda-1)y\|)\\
&\le \frac1{|\lambda^2-2|}(|\lambda+1|\|x\|+\|y\| + \|x\|+|\lambda-1|\|y\|)\\
&\le \frac{\max\{1+|\lambda+1|, 1+|\lambda-1|\}}{|\lambda^2-2|}(\|x\|+\|y\|)\\
&= \frac{\max\{1+|\lambda+1|, 1+|\lambda-1|\}}{|\lambda^2-2|}\left\|\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix}\right\|\\
\end{align}
so $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is bounded. However, this also follows from the Bounded Inverse Theorem once you verify that $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ is indeed the algebraic inverse of the bounded map $T-\lambda I$.

Comment: So the matrix can be used to express $T$ although it isn't $T$ itself? And you conclude that the residual and continuous spectrum are empty because for $\lambda \neq \pm \sqrt{2}$ we get that $\lambda\notin\sigma(T)$ right?

Comment: @mandella Yes, the matrix is merely a tool to guess what points could be in the spectrum. Yes, and $\pm\sqrt{2}$ are eigenvalues.

Comment: When you calculate $(T-\lambda I)^{-1}$, should the matrix at the end when you find the inverse have the ${-1}$? and also why is it bounded?

Comment: @mandella I think the matrix is ok, notice the minus in front. I added the explanation why it's bounded.

Comment: OK, I see the proof! Thank you. One more teeny thing: I got the eigenvectors to be $[\mp\sqrt{2}\pm1)y, y]$ for $\lambda=\pm\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @mandella I believe $1\pm \sqrt{2}$ is correct because
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1\pm\sqrt{2} \\ 1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2\pm\sqrt{2} \\ \pm\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix} = \pm\sqrt{2} \begin{bmatrix}1\pm\sqrt{2}\\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$